# How to convert a table into a Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark SQL, a dataframe can be queried as a table using this:

```
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df, "mytable")
```

Assuming what I have is `mytable`, how can I get or access this as a DataFrame?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well you can query it and save the result into a variable. Check that `SQLContext`'s method [sql](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=sqlcontext#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.sql) returns a `DataFrame`.

```py
df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM mytable")
```

Answer (score 37):

The cleanest way:

```
df = sqlContext.table("mytable")
```

[Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=table#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.table)