# Is it Possible to Write the Contents of a Temporary View in Spark SQL?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to write the contents of a Temporary View created in Spark SQL to a given path?

Let's say I create a Temp View using the following,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW tmp
AS
SELECT *
FROM parquet.`dbfs:/mnt/path/to/read/dir`
```

How can I write `tmp` to something like a CSV file to a chosen path like `dbfs:/mnt/path/to/write/dir`?

I know that you can write the contents of a DataFrame using something like,

```
df.write.format("csv").save(filepath)
```

You can change the format parameter to allow the contents to be written to a format of choice.

Is something similar available for Temp Views?

Comment: did you try converting TempView to dataframe if you are trying to write it to CSV using dataframe like - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191194/how-to-convert-a-table-into-a-spark-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Above Spark 2.0

```
df=spark.sql("<query>")
df.write.format("csv").save(filepath)
```

Comment: This is again, writing a DataFrame, right? My question is if a `TEMP VIEW` can be written to a file.

Comment: Need more info on the scenario. You might have to check the temp location for your user session to load the file data